# How can I stop when [1, 2] comes out. Is it an error of 'break'?

Tags: python

I want to print 2 random numbers, except if the numbers are `[1, 2]`. However, the code I've tried doesn't stop even when `[1, 2]` appears.

I tried 3 types of `while` loop,  but they all had similar problems.

```py
import random
count == 0
while count == 0:
    print(random.sample(range(1, 7), 2))
    if random.sample(range(1, 7), 2) == [1, 2]:
        break

while random.sample(range(1, 7), 2) != [1, 2, 3]:
    print(random.import(range(1, 7), 2))

while 1:
    print(random.sample(range(1, 7), 2))
    if random.sample(range(1, 7), 2) == [1, 2]:
        break
```

I want to stop when [1, 2] appear.

Comment: Are you sure this does not stop? You are printing a different list that the one doing the equals, so this will print something different than `[1,2]`

Answer (score 5):

The evaluation in your `if` statement was totally different from what you were printing.

```
print(random.sample(range(1, 7), 2))  # this prints 2 numbers
if random.sample(range(1, 7), 2) == [1, 2]:  # but thhis calls random again and gets a 2 totally different numbers.
```

You need to assign to a variable your numbers and check those with `[1, 2]`

Try this (also you can change your while likewise, you dont need a counter):

```
import random

while True:
    nums = random.sample(range(1, 7), 2)
    print(nums)
    if nums == [1, 2]:
        break
```